# command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 (installing psyco)

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-errors

I run Ubuntu 11.10, gcc version 4.6.1.

I've been trying to install psyco, but keep getting this error:

```
PROCESSOR = 'i386'
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psyco._psyco' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DALL_STATIC=1 -Ic/i386 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/psyco.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/c/psyco.o
In file included from c/initialize.h:55:0,
                 from c/psyco.c:14:
c/mergepoints.c:242:3: error: ‘JUMP_IF_FALSE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
c/mergepoints.c:242:3: error: ‘JUMP_IF_TRUE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
c/codegen.c:127:19: warning: ‘psyco_source_condition’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
c/codegen.c:747:10: warning: ‘integer_lshift’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
c/Objects/plistobject.c:115:10: warning: ‘PsycoList_SingletonNew’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've installed python-setuptools but nothing worked so far. Thanks for a ny suggestions.

Comment: Try installing build-essential, as well as python2.x-dev (where x is your python version)

Comment: Tried both, they are installed to the latest version

Comment: Psyco is pretty much dead. Consider using Cython or PyPy if you need speed.

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend: psyco does not build and does not work with Python 2.7, as documented in the corresponding [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/psyco/+bug/685177).

Why do you require Psyco? If you need to optimize tight loops, possibly [Cython](http://cython.org/) can come to your rescue.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should get "https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries" install path :C:/mingw and Installation path ：C:/mingw/bin .Finally, find distutils.cfg at the python installation directory D:/Python26/Lib/distutils

Comment: [build]
compiler=mingw32

Comment: The asker has indicated that they are using Ubuntu, a linux distro, while your answer is very windows specific and targeted exactly towards your installation.